# 1980s sci-fi book club trilogy about a rich, space-faring multi-generational family

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of 1980s sci-fi book club trilogy about a multi-generational family. The covers had faces on them and the matriarch had a white streak in her hair. Rich family, space-faring and it had family trees in it. I got it from the Science Fiction Book Club some time in the 80s.

Comment: Can you remember any actual events? Did they have a ship? How did they make their money? What was interesting about them?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3015969-venus-of-dreams?

Comment: As Sean indicates, that is most likely Damia, but she was not the matriarch (that is the Rowan who has white hair).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the *[Children of the Stars](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57013-children-of-the-stars)* series by *[Juanita Coulson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juanita_Coulson)*. Book 1, *[Tomorrow's Heritage](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1987315.Tomorrow_s_Heritage)*, was released by the SFBC in 1981 and the cover matches your description:

[image]

The series was however 4 books, not a trilogy. A description for book 1 is as follows:

> "A futuristic, post-cataclysmic, sci-fi soap opera. On an Earth whose
>   population has been decimated and whose landscape has been forcibly
>   altered by natural causes and the effects of humankind's weapons,
>   political and national boundaries have been altered. The Saunder
>   family has gained wealth and power due to the actions of the
>   manipulative matriarch, and the three offspring are in positions of
>   great power and responsibility. But the family has cracks that
>   ultimately will risk tearing the family apart. And into this volatile
>   mix comes news that an alien spacecraft is approaching Earth."

The series does progress later to space-faring. With the Saunders family spending vast amounts of their fortune to aid in the development of faster-than-light technology.

> *Her clothes were the ultimate in fashion. Her hands were soft and beautiful. **Her lustrous hair, stylishly middle-length, displayed that
>   attractive white streak that was Jael’s trademark.** She covered her
>   excess weight with loose, long-sleeved tunics over pants or half
>   saris. The outfits flattered her busty figure. She was really doing
>   fine, and she knew it. She just wanted to hear her devoted family tell
>   her so.*

Comment: I'm not seeing a white streak in her hair...

Comment: The book often refers to her white streak. The cover had alot of light in this picture, and I couldn't find a less glossy one, but there are a few visable above the womans left eye going back. Multiple though, not just 1 streak.

Comment: This is it - thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

It's possible that you're referring to Anne McCaffrey's *[The Rowan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan)* series. [Damia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damia_(novel)), her daughter, has a white streak in her hair. They're definitely rich. Space-faring is a bit trickier of a link in that they generally remain planet-bound, but they do interface with space. They were released in the early 90s, but it's close to your timeframe.

[image: Front cover of hardback of Damia]

Comment: Hi.  I'm wondering why you wrote "Dame McCaffrey" and not "Anne McCaffrey"?  I'd edit it, but maybe you did this on purpose and I'm missing something?

Comment: @basya There was a time when people often referred to her as such. I'd assumed she actually held a title of some sort, so I customarily added it. Now, poking around, it looks like it was a temporary affectation, so I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks, and interesting...

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the  Galactic Milieu Series?

> The series begins with *Intervention: A Root Tale to the Galactic
>   Milieu and a Vinculum between it and The Saga of Pliocene Exile*
>   (1987). This was released in one volume in the UK, but in mass market
>   paperback in the USA as two volumes: *Surveillance* and *Metaconcert*.
>   May calls *Intervention* a vinculum, or link-tale, between the Saga of
>   Pliocene Exile and the Milieu trilogy proper. However, it is a
>   near-essential introduction to the Milieu trilogy as well as a
>   balanced stand-alone work.
>
> *Jack the Bodiless* (1991) is the first book of the trilogy proper,
>   followed by *Diamond Mask* (1994), and *Magnificat* (1996).

[Series summary](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/GalacticMilieu):

> The Galactic Milieu Series by Julian May describes the struggle of the
>   most powerful of the human metapsychics and their interaction with a
>   galactic confederation of exotic beings.
>
> The entire story takes place over roughly a 150 year period, starting
>   with the birth of the narrator in 1945. History starts to diverge
>   wildly and obviously from ours in the mid 80s as psychic research
>   becomes mainstream due to the actual existence of people with operant
>   mind powers.

If you look at the "Look Inside" sample of [Magnificat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345362497) at Amazon.com, you can see the family tree(s) in the beginning. This  is the Remillard Family, or Dynasty.

There's a really good description/summary of each of the books in the series on the [Galactic Milieu wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Milieu_Series#Plots_of_the_novels).